# Why is SunBurst background so popular and are there any other ones?

Tags: website-design, psychology

I keep seeing [SunBurst Background Pattern](http://www.google.com/search?&q=sunburst&tbm=isch) for years, literally! and it is still trendy. Why is it still so? Do we lack creativity for similar generic (or focus drawing) background patterns or human psychology has bias against it?

Secondly, have there been any other so obvious background pattern trends?

Note: I asked the question in [graphicdesign.stackexchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/why-is-sunburst-background-so-popular-and-are-there-any-other-ones) at first. Having got no answer and having doubts on the appropriate site for this question, I decided to ask here as well. If this parallel questioning against the rules of SE, I might just as well delete one.

UPDATE

A few examples from a [Smashing Magazine piece on website backgrounds](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/31/backgrounds-in-web-design-examples-and-best-practices-2/).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Definitely belongs on graphicdesign and not here.

Comment: @Patrick McElhaney, which part didn't you understand? Those people in graphics.stackexchange.com don't have any problem with this question, apparently http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2718/why-is-sunburst-background-so-popular-and-are-there-any-other-ones

Comment: I see you got some answers on the original question on graphic design, so there doesn't seem to be much value in keeping it here.

Comment: @Patrick McElhaney, I think, this question is just as related to UX as to graphicdesign. It could still beneficial for the members of ux.SE. So, you might as well reopen it.

Comment: @Comptrol - see Jeff's response here: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/407/shouldnt-moderators-be-following-se-rules-when-responding-to-flags-and-closing-q/416#416 for more information on why it was and should remain closed.

Comment: @Charles, Jeff himself reopened it (see his latest comment on same link).

Comment: @Vitaly - still not a real question.

Comment: @Charles, if you cite Jeff as the authority when it supports your claim, then shouldn't you recognize his authority also when it doesn't..? As someone has recently said on meta, _very inconsistent_. Jin also thinks that it's on-topic - poorly worded, but on-topic.

Comment: @Vitaly - Absolutely nothing inconsistent in my response. Jeff gave a valid reason why it should be closed. He now reopened it for a really stupid reason. The question has absolutely nothing to do with UX and it isn't a real question to begin with, just random musings.

Comment: @Vitaly - see this answer: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8705/why-is-sunburst-background-so-popular-and-are-there-any-other-ones/8935#8935 It's a great example of the kind of answers this type of question will generate, and a great example of why this question is not appropriate for the site.

Comment: @Charles, see this answer: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8705/why-is-sunburst-background-so-popular-and-are-there-any-other-ones/8711#8711. It's a great example of the kind of answers this type of question will generate, and a great example of why this question is appropriate for the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This pattern works because it focuses the viewer's eyes onto the product sold/blog entry/whatever content. It does have a simple psychological trick that is probably better understood with photographic backgrounds.

Take a really beautiful photo that is well composed with a foreground subject in the middle and nicely framed by the background. You may have plenty of candidate photos in your own collection from various places around the world.

Now stretch it up to fill a webpage background and put a 960px wide column of content over the top. This obliterates the foreground subject of the photo and a large part of the background. However, the outer, framing of background is still present and still has the qualities that made it work so well in the original picture. Because of this it works really well as a background.

The starburst picture is similar in that even with the middle missing it still serves to focus the eye on the centre.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but I've seen a lot of 'starburst' backgrounds where the sun is placed in one of the corners, or at least off-centre. I'd probably put this one down to plain old fashion.